# Using skewness and kurtosis functions in image matching

Tags: matlab, colors, computer-vision, histogram

I am using the skewness and kurtosis functions  for image color Histogram in image retrieval system as a statistical  color features then using these features to compare between two images to retrieve the similarity images....but I get 'NaN' value  in some results which is causes an error in image retrieval process:

```
S=double(imread('im.jpg');
         R=S(:,:,1)/64;      R1=floor(R);  
         G=S(:,:,2)/64;      G1=floor(G);
         B=S(:,:,3)/64;      B1=floor(B);
 [rr cc c]=size(R1); 
         ImageHist = zeros(4,4,4);
              for row = 1 :rr
                      for col = 1:cc
                            ImageHist(R1(row,col)+1, G1(row,col)+1,B1(row,col)+1 )= ImageHist(R1(row,col)+1, G1(row,col)+1,B1(row,col)+1)+1;                   
                     end
              end

             ImageHist = ImageHist/(rr*cc);
```

then I compute the Kurtosis as:

```
QKurColHis = kurtosis(ImageHist);
```

I make the same thing to second function (skewness)

It is suitable to use this function to the color histogram to extract color feature? then using it in image retrieval?

if it is OK, how can I correct  this Error, how can I remove the `NaN` values from my mat.file?

I want to use these function as image features in matching between color images... any one please could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: indeed, you ask the questions, take the answers, but put nothing back

Comment: At the very least, you should upvote good answers to your own questions.  You do have the reputation for that.

Comment: Hi Dima.... I didn't get the answer to my own question to up vote it.. no one tell me how can I used these function to extract image color feature or why I get NaN values? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the builtin kurtosis function is working but it might be that you have to supply it a vector instead of 3D matrix as an input

```
kurtosis(ImageHist(:))
```

Apart from the NaN problem, kurtosis and skewness give you some info about statistical distribution of the data in ImageHist so they could be treated as some image features. But how good will they perform in image matching is hard to say.